# Android WebView "Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-webview

I am trying to run a web page in a WebView. The page that I am loading has javascript in it, and it works on my desktop browser but doesn't work in the android emulator. In the emulator, I get this error:

> 09-13 18:29:18.496 32087-32087/com.gamesmart.gamesmart I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(91)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined", source: http://dev.gamesmart.com/mobile (91)

The JavaScript that I am running on the page looks like this:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
        var items = document.querySelectorAll('a.item');
        for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
            var item = items[i];
            item.addEventListener('click', function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                window.JSInterface.playGame(items[i].getAttribute('href'));
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Then The Java that I am running looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;
    private WebViewClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        JavaScriptInterface jsInterface = new JavaScriptInterface(this);

        // Setup the WebView
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        webView.setInitialScale(1);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        webView.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "JSInterface");

        // Load a default URL into the webview
        webView.loadUrl("http://dev.gamesmart.com/mobile");
    }

}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing this

`window.JSInterface.playGame(items[i].getAttribute('href'));`

with this

```
window.JSInterface.playGame(item.getAttribute('href'));
```

Comment: I saw that and changed it, it looks like I am getting a new error now! Looks like this might have been the issue...